# Downloaded game onto my external hard drive, but Steam won't let me play the game?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam

Steam is saying I have to download the game all over again, but I have already done so. It is on my external hard drive instead of my SSD in my laptop, to save space. I haven't really had this problem before, any ideas what may have happened?

Comment: Did your external hard drive's drive letter change?

Comment: Is this the first time you've installed a game to this external drive? Did Steam install it there, or did you move it there manually? Has the drive been unplugged since installing the game to it?

Comment: Have you set that specific HD+directory as a Steam Library inside Steam?

Answer (score 2):

The game needs to be in the correct folder.

It has to be in your `<Steam Directory>\Steam\SteamApps\common` folder. If it is in one, make sure Steam recognizes it.

Comment: @AshCat If this answer solved your problem, you should accept it. Both of you will get rep for that.

Answer (score -1):

I would try clearing some space and installing Skyrim on your SSD.

Steam tends to be picky about which folders it'll pick from.